# Cordova command not found in mac

Tags: cordova, npm, hybrid

I have checked in ".`node/lib`" folder, there is `cordova` is available 
Still i am getting error Command not found error. I have installed cordova using `npm install -g cordova` and also try `sudo npm install -g cordova`.